# Recommendations for best running watches for syncing to smartphones?

Tags: running

My Garmin Forerunner 225 sucks at syncing to my phone and that is an important feature to me.  Are there newer Garmin models or other brands that have bulletproof connectivity for smartphones?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is about a fitness device, it is about operation/syncing, not how to use the device in the context of a fitness program.

Comment: I am asking about recommendations for fitness gadgets, relating to specific functionality. Per the help center guidelines "gear and gadgets used during exercise" is allowed and asking for suggestions and recommendations should fall within the bounds. Those aspects are within the typical bounds of questions about these devices and they are not specifically disallowed in the guidelines.

Comment: "Used during exercise" means how you use it in an actual exercise regimen. That does not include "What syncs really well?"

Comment: I believe you are misreading that. Its describing the kind of gear, not what usages thereof can be discussed. Assuming I can't convince you, what other stackexchange site would be a better fit for this type of question?

Comment: I took a look through our meta, and [this question/answer](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/are-questions-about-fitbit-etc-considered-off-topic/) from a long time moderator indicates that "Aspects of gadgets outside of the use for fitness, such as the economics of fitness are not on topic.". So I would consider what syncs best to be in the same vein. However, it is a bit of an undefined area, so I will work on a good meta post to determine where the boundaries are.

Comment: In the meantime, I would highly recommend [DC Rainmaker's blog](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/) for some of his reviews. Independent and realistic, and very good review style.

Comment: Dan - Posted on meta.